# response.sendRedirect() in Spring vs JSF

Tags: spring, jsf, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

All,

I've hit a roadblock implementing OpenId due to some unexpected behavior storing session information.

The basic outline is as follows

```
// In OpenId Initialize Servlet
request.getSession().setAttribute("isLinkingRequired", true);
response.sendRedirect(openIdUrl);

// In Open ID Verify Servlet
boolean linkCheck = request.getSession().getAttribute("isLinkingRequired") != null
```

The sample provided to me by Intuit is written with Spring.  In the Spring app, linkCheck evaluates to true.  The previously stored session information is there.

My app is written with JSF (in particular, Oracle's ADF framework).  In my case linkCheck evaluates to false.  All previous stored session attributes are gone!

This has caused me a boatload of problems.  Can anyone explain this odd behaviour?

Comment: First confirm you're dealing with the same session (by way of JSESSION_ID). There's a bunch of context still necessary here. Is this happening on button-click? In a servlet?

Comment: To kick things off, I paste a link into the browser.  Then everything is sent through the two servlets above.  There's no UI interaction going on.  I may have to do some more experiments to determine session information.